# Flutter webview resume app from Background show white screen when navigator pop from second page

Tags: ios, webview, flutter

I have 2 pages of my app. Home page and Second page. I have Webveiw and one button in home page. Click button to load Second page. After load second page, i force app to Background. When I resume app, and click Navigator back in Second page, it show white blank screen over my home page. I don't know where that white blank page is coming from. It make me cannot see my home page.

In home page, I have Webview and RaisedButton:

```
new WebView(
                key: _key,
                initialUrl: 'https://www.google.com/',
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  _controller = webViewController;
                }
```

```
new RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondPage()),
                  );
                }
```

When I click RaisedButton, open second page and then force app to background.
After resume app from Background and click Navigator back to home page, it pop up blank white screen over my home page.

Comment: This problem is in iOS only, for Android is working fine

Comment: How could you solve this ? Please share the solution for us.